# How to append / prepend into a rich text field

Tags: templating, richtext

I have a rich text field, e.g. for defining an image caption. Now in my template I would like to prepend some text to the content of the rich text field, e.g. *Figure 1:* [rich text]. Is this possible? The content of the paragraph-tag of the rich text field should include the prepended text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to prepend another paragraph you could to this:

```
{% set paragraphs = entry.body|split('</p>') %}
{% for paragraph in paragraphs %}
  {% if loop.index == 1%}
    <p>Prepended Custom Text</p>
  {% endif %}
    {{paragraph|raw}}
{% endfor %}
```

If you want to display a custom string in the first paragraph itself you could do this:

```
{% set paragraphs = entry.body|split('</p>') %}
{% for paragraph in paragraphs %}
  {% if loop.index == 1%}
    {% set paragraph = paragraph|replace({'<p>': '<p>My custom prepended Text '}) %}
  {% endif %}
    {{paragraph|raw}}
{% endfor %}
```

This looks a little bit hacky tough there are probably prettier ways to do so.